# Systemd taking a very long time to boot

Tags: boot, systemd

This morning I turned on my PC and suddenly it took extremely long time to boot (usually less than 10s), I did `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and this was the result:

```
graphical.target @1min 39.673s
└─multi-user.target @1min 39.673s
  └─sendmail.service @1min 37.606s +2.067s
    └─network-online.target @1min 37.598s
      └─network.target @1min 30.846s
        └─ifup@as0t15.service @1min 40.386s
          └─apparmor.service @3.243s +88ms
            └─local-fs.target @3.241s
              └─media-vilsol-0184CF876B4E35E3.mount @2min 58.338s
                └─local-fs-pre.target @3.241s
                  └─systemd-remount-fs.service @3.235s +4ms
                    └─systemd-fsck-root.service @3.210s +24ms
                      └─system.slice @193ms
                        └─-.slice @193ms
```

The main thing that popped out to me is

`└─media-vilsol-0184CF876B4E35E3.mount @2min 58.338s`

I have no idea why that is taking so insanely long, it never used to. Is there a way I can check what is wrong or something?

Comment: Does the long boot time persist? I'd think it was maybe a filesystem check.

Comment: @Nephente yes, restarted multiple times, same thing happens

Comment: Is this a disk? Check it for failing (with `badblocks`). Not to scare you, but I had the same symptoms and after a couple of weeks my HD died. *backup!*